# Outlets go in and out and turning my stove on will turn them back on

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 7 outlets in my kitchen and they will go out and I can turn on my electric stove and they come back on

Comment: It sounds like a loss neutral.  Phone your power company right now to check the wires.

Comment: Not a lost neutral, but a lost hot.  The large stove **or water heater** load is functionally putting a low value resistor between the dead phase and the live phase, "bringing those circuits back to life" in a sort of broken way.

Answer (score 4):

You likely have either a lost leg or a lost neutral. This is a **SERIOUS PROBLEM**. It can happen at the main panel, at a subpanel (if the problem circuits are all on a subpanel and other circuits from the main panel are OK) or it can be a utility problem. It is most often a utility problem because the utility connections are exposed and subject to wind, rain, etc.

- Turn off everything you can, because the wild voltage swings can damage a lot of equipment.
- CALL YOUR ELECTRIC UTILITY. Tell them you are having problems and think there is a lost neutral. If they have no idea what you are talking about (depends on how well they train the people who answer the trouble calls) just tell them you have an intermittent OUTAGE. They should dispatch someone pretty quickly unless there are significant weather-related outages in your area.

If the utility checks remotely and says "everything looks OK", tell them the problem is intermittent and that they need to send a truck.

Once they send somebody out, if they find the problem they will likely fix it quickly and at no charge. If they don't find any problem, *then* you need to call an electrician to check for a problem in your main panel.